# Scale up applet's graphics size

Tags: java, applet, resolution

I want to double the size of an applet (including the graphics and components positioned on it).

Is there any easy way to accomplish this before I start changing every coordinate individually?

Comment: When you say "every coordinate" - do you mean that all the panels are positioned using a XY pixel position?  If your using a layout manager which handles the size/position of things relatively it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Panels are positioned using XY. Graphics are drawn on some of the panels also using XY. It's going to be very painful if I have to multiply every draw coordinate manually.

Comment: *"Panels are positioned using XY."*  1) If layouts were used (properly) the GUI would expand or contract to fit the available space. If overriding `paint()/paintComponent()`, it is your responsibility to scale the rendering of the `Graphics`. 2) You might do this exactly as you would do it in a `JFrame` (so it has little to do with applets). 3) An applet is normally not resizable, so how is this 'scaling' to be accomplished? 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I wrote a Java applet, so I cannot tell you exactly which classes and interfaces.

But as a general principle you could do this with a decorator. Make a class that implements the same interface as your graphics context object*. Pass the actual graphics context to the constructor of your class. For each method on your class, call the same method on the graphic context object that it wraps. And set the magnification as a field of the class so you can make it 3x in future.

Then, when your code takes the graphics object, replace that with an instance of your custom class, which should wrap the graphics object.

If this is not possible, you may have to hack your original code. But take my advice - this time include a multiplication factor as a variable/field so that next time you can adjust the number in once place.

- or, if there's no interface available, which looks to be the the [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class, extend it and be sure to override every method.

Answer (score 0):

If the applet contents scale you just need to change the size of the applet in the embedding html page. This assumes that only relative or calculated coordinates and layout managers have been used. If elements are positioned at absolute positions, this will not work will. Then you will either have to touch the code or write a wrapper that scales the content, as Joe suggested.

Comment: Even if that does work (I'm not sure it will) then you'd lose efficiency in the frame buffer.

Comment: Right, it (the zoom hack) probably works in too few browser/OS combinations to be really useful. Just scaling the applet in the embedding HTML doesn't seem to do the trick, if I interpret the poster's comment correctly, looks like absolute coordinates are used.

Comment: We may be reading the question differently... hope the OP will make it a bit clearer.

Comment: I tried it on different browsers and OS, the scaling trick does not work (anymore - I am certain it did at a time).